# DocuSign Correct and Resend Template Tags

Tags: templates, soap, tags, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API and I was trying to correct and resend some envelopes. However one of the corrections I would like to make is template based. For instance, I sent out an envelope with some templates, however, one of the template's tags needs to be removed or be changed to not required. I can change the envelope's template tags in the DS gui but I can't seem to find a way to do it in the SOAP API. Conclusively, I want to be able to correct the tags of an envelope though code. Is there a way to this?

Comment: Are you using REST or SOAP API?

Comment: I am using the SOAP API.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this through either API, however you might be able to POST the correction view and allow the user to make those changes through the Web console.  I think the call only exists in REST, but check out the `POST Envelope Correction` [api call](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=200).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this through either API (SOAP or REST).  In DocuSign when you are correcting an in-process envelope you can alter properties about the recipients themselves and their authentication methods and info, but you can not modify their tabs (once the envelope has been sent).

For instance, you can change a given recipient's `email`, `name`, `routingOrder`, or you can change things like their `accessCode`s, `captiveInfo`, etc, but as mentioned you can not alter the tabs.

For a more complete answer, in SOAP the corresponding API call for making envelope corrections is `CorrectAndResendEnvelope`.
For more info [Recipient Corrections in SOAP API](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf#page=116).

In REST the corresponding call for making recipient corrections is: `Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information`.  For more info [Recipient Corrections in REST API](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=191).

Comment: The link that you are provided was broken.